# c# WPF How to invoke or call button function using string variable, the string variable contains the button name?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
string buttonName="";  
private void _1btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    var button = (Button) sender; 
    buttonName = button.Name;
    ChangeButtonColour();
} 

private void ChangeButtonColour() {
    buttonName.Background = Brushes.Red;// doesn't Work!
}
```

I'm try to call the button function using the string variable buttonName(Which contains "_1btn")  rather than calling _1btn which is the actually button Name.

Comment: I don't know your code but I suggest you to add the **button object** to a `dictionary` instead of save the button's name.

Comment: Does your code compile? Background is not a property of string.

Comment: No it doesnt complie, background is a property of a button. Im trying to invoke the background property using the string variable which contains the button name.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //find the control by from form element tree
    private void ChangeButtonColour(string _btname)
    {
        Button foundTextBox = FindChild<Button>(Application.Current.MainWindow, _btname);
    }

    public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)where T : DependencyObject
    {
        // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
        if (parent == null) return null;

        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            // If the child is not of the request child type child
            T childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                // recursively drill down the tree
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                // If the child's name is set for search
                if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                {
                    // if the child's name is of the request name
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // child element found.
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. You can't store the button properties in a string variable. So you have create a button object type variable then assign the button to the new button type variable and then you can call the button properties.

```
Button buttonName="";  

private void _1btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){    
buttonName = _1btn;
ChangeButtonColour();
} 

private void ChangeButtonColour() {
buttonName.Background = Brushes.Red;// This works!
}
```